# how add Powered by: on a banner advertising?

Tags: html, css

example: [Ads by: Google](https://google.com)

This is the banner css, in this banner i want to add on top left (Ads by: mysite.com)

```
 .mybannerads {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1000;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do it in CSS only, you can use the `:before` pseudo-element and then style it accordingly.

```
.mybannerads:before {
    content: "Ads by: mysite.com";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, is possible to make this clicable?

Comment: You would need to add this via the markup or Javascript unfortunately.